# making each line double vim

Tags: shell, vim, vi

I have a file which looks like this:

```
file1
file2
file3
.
.
.
filen
```

I want to convert it to :

```
echo "file1"
cat file1
echo "file2"
cat file2
.
.
.
.
echo "filen"
cat filen
```

One way can be to have a for loop and read the content of original file and write modified content to another file , I did that and it worked. Is there any command to do the same in `vim` through `:g` or any other command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
:%s/.*/echo "\0"\rcat \0/g
```

***Explanation:***

`:%s/a/b/g` means search whole file and replace `a` to `b`.

`.*` means match every thing in one line.

`\0` means the matched thing.

`\r` means the new line.

Comment: awesome ... is there anything in the world you cannot do with vim :) .. It will be great if you can add an explanation on how it works ..thanks

Comment: @nav_jan: it doesn't wash dishes. That's for Emacs to do.

Comment: @xdazz why did you change your answer `:%s/\(.*\)/echo "\1"\rcat \1/g` worked perfectly for me?

Comment: @nav_jan because this one aslo work,  but shorter, check my edit.

Comment: @fork0 In vim `\r` is the new line.

Comment: @xdazz depends on what you consider "new line": there is no official symbol named "new line". There is, though, a "Carriage Return" (which is \r, aka CR) and there is a "Line Feed": \n aka LF, aka NL. Seec ascii(1). But right, vim inserts \0, if \n is used, I'm sorry for pedantic. I actually always use Ctrl-V, Enter

Comment: my solution maybe ... `:%s/.*/echo "&"\rcat "&"/g`

Answer (score 3):

alternatively you could apply a macro

```
yypha"<esc>^iecho "<esc>j^icat <esc>j
```

- `yypha"` yanks the current line puts it below the current and go up with `h`
- `a"<esc>` appends a `"` and goes back to normal mode
- `^iecho "<esc>` puts `echo "` in front of the `file*` and again goes to normal
- `j^icat<esc>` prepends cat on the next line and
- `j` at last goes to the next line to be ready for reapplying the macro

you can either record the macro by pressing `qq` and the buttons as described or

write `yypha"^[^iecho "^[j^icat ^[j` with **`^[`** being entered as `Ctrl-V` then `Esc` and then `"qyy` to yank the line in the q-th register, which is then also an executable macro.

The macro itself you can run with `@q` once or `30@q` thirty times.

Comment: yeah without explanation macros are hard to get. but coolest is that macros are stored in a register (here q) so you can paste&edit it and yank it back into the register - so mistyping a macro is no reason to restart recording the macro.

Comment: how to view the content of a register ?

Comment: you can either type `:reg` or just paste it for example in an empty file with `"qp` (paste register q)

Answer (score 1):

I'd usually go with the accepted answer, but just to show that command-mode (Ex) commands can be nice too:

> <kbd>`:g/^./t. | norm!` `icat␣`<kbd>^O</kbd>`k`<kbd>^O</kbd>`0echo␣"`<kbd>^O</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>`"`</kbd>

<sup>Note: enter the keycodes using <kbd>^V</kbd> (e.g. <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>^O</kbd>). On windows,   <kbd>^Q</kbd> has that function by default)</sup>

Explanation

- `:g/^./` (repeat for every line containing at least one char)
- `t.`     (duplicate the line below)
- the rest:

  - insert `'cat ``,
  - <kbd>^O</kbd>`k` (up a line)
  - ^O`0` (at start of line)
  - insert `'echo "'`
  - append `'"'` at end of line

Comment: Why do you need `^O` before the `0`, but not before the `A`?

Comment: @sg-lecram Oops. That somehow went AWOL. Thanks for the heads up, I've fixed that

Answer (score 0):

A variation on [@xdazz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11360422/327074). You can do this only using Vim's regex:

```
:%s/\(.*\)/\1\r\1
```

- `\(.*\)` adds the whole line to the `\1` register
- `\1\r\1` duplicates the line with a newline in between